# Angular 8: Assign Date Values to Type Moment

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript, angular8

How do I assign to Type Moment in Angular 8 Typescript?
I am getting error,

```
"dateStart":"2/5/2019"
```

> Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Moment'.ts

I have a class, and want to set values in this class for moment.

```
export class Address {
    fullName: string;
    mailingAddress: string;
    phoneNumber: string;
    emailAddress: string;
    dateStart?: moment.Moment;
    dateEnd?: moment.Moment;

this.address = [ 
  {
       "fullName":"John Smith", 
       "mailingAddress":"Oak Street", 
       "phoneNumber":"742-351-4195", 
       "emailAddress":"JohnSmith@gmail.com", 
       "dateStart":moment('20.02.2018 09:19'), 
       "dateEnd":moment('20.09.2018 09:19')
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the variable you are trying to assign to a type of string,

```
someVariable : string;
```

EDIT

If you want a [`moment`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/) date from a string, Try to convert as

```
"dateStart": moment('02-05-2019',"MM-DD-YYYY")
```

Comment: just cast the string to type you need as shown above

Comment: my bad , corrected. you can check the formats from the above link given

Comment: thanks, this helps set and assign the value for moment in Angular